# C++ (for) Написать программу, которая выводит на экран квадрат (пользователь вводит длину стороны), состоящий из символа '*'

Tags: c#, c++, c

как это написать? 
и использовать только "for"

Comment: Один или два можно? :)

Comment: @Harry на C# вообще можно без циклов (не считая цикла под капотом применяемого метода). да и вообще циклы не нужны для такого задания :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Можно и без циклов. Например, рекурсивно :)

Comment: А квадрат должен быть закрашен или только стороны изобразить его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(N) << '*' << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Этому вопросу не хватает LINQ.

```
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var n) ?
    string.Join("\n", Enumerable.Repeat(new string('*', n), n)) :
    "Не число");
```